# How to run a shell and docker executor on the same unix host?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I would like to use the same host computer to execute Docker builds using the shell executor, as described in the link below, and normal builds using the docker executor.

I would like to be able to start builds of both types on the same host.

I would like to use the debian package provided for Ubuntu and installed via ant from the repository.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html

In other words, if I run a project to build docker containers, the shell executor should run the commands against docker. If I build a source code project, the docker executor should run my build inside a docker container.

Can someone please describe the steps required to achieve such a configuration.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you sure it's any different than running the executors on separate machines?

Comment: Yes, it seems I can only install one executor during package installation and there is only one daemon account. But I require two different executors on one runner.

Comment: You can register multiple runners. The repo even has an example of config.toml with different executors: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/blob/master/config.toml.example

Comment: Hi Jakub, also found that after some digging. Can you rephrase as an answer, so I can accept? Or do you want me to answer the question myself?

Comment: I think it would be best if you answer it.

Comment: @JakubKania, it would be really nice if you could answer this yourself - you found the solution after all :)!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Run `gitlab-runner register` multiple times. It will always append new configurations to the same `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` file.

Comment: Just as an information. If you do this directly on the hostmachine you dont have an actual docker executor that will run inside a docker container. The host will start a docker container to run jobs. But the docker executor itself is running on the host machine directly. 

Both ways are working but there are some security considerations that may have to be taken into account to prevent access to the host machine. This is not following the installation guide regarding the docker executor of gitlab itself.

Comment: @Retrogott Its been few years, since I setup these last time, but I briefly reviewed the docs and did not find any pointers that one should manually setup a container where to run the docker executer. Though I usually setup the gitlab runner inside its own VM. Please add an answer if you have some better information and references about it and the best practises https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#docker-executor-workflow https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/

Comment: You are right. I  had a misconception between installing the runner in a docker image and using a gitlab runner docker executor. I were refereing to the [Installation guide for a Gitlab Runner on Docker](https://docs.gitlab.com/15.9/runner/install/docker.html)